# Get LineString length in meters

Tags: python, geometry, linestring, length

I have a series of LineString that I want to have the length in meters. I use the shapely.geometry module, and importing LineString.

I've seen this post, explaining how to do it, but it seems using Django : [Get LineString length in meters (Python, GEODjango)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180776/get-linestring-length-in-meters-python-geodjango/181251#181251)

```
# Create a line string
>>> line = LineString([(0, 0), (360, 0)])

# Specify srid using [WGS84][1]
>>> line.srid = 4326

# Transform into projected coordinate system (using web mercator)
>>> line.transform(3857)

# Line length. This is zero within numerical precision, because the start 
# point (0, 0) is the same as the end point (0, 360)) on a map.
>>> line.length
>>> 1.1329847282581795e-08

# An example forcing the line through the other side of the world,
# and specifying srid on definition.
>>> line = LineString([(0, 0), (180, 0), (360, 0)], srid=4326)
>>> line.tansform(3857)
>>> line.length
>>> 40075016.6855784
```

I try to use this post, but it makes me the following error :

```
'LineString' object has no attribute 'lenght'
```

IS there any module to import?

Comment: ***Never*** trust the distance returned by Web Mercator. Unless you're measuring along the equator, it is effectively useless.

Comment: Why @Vince? Do you have any suggestion in return?

Comment: The defects of distance measurement  in Web Mercator are well known, but Google Maps used it, so it became a standard for mapping, despite the infinite distance from the Equator to the poles. Since the example is only measuring the Equator, it is demonstrating implicit wrapping, but since almost any other projection is better for distance (and custom equidistant or equal area projections are most appropriate), documenting this quirk is of little real value. Your error is simple spelling (t before h).

Comment: Ok interesting ! I used another system to calculate it, I will show it on answer to this question. And for the answer, yes, it's true, I didn't see that... Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a point of clarification;
with [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/index.html) 2.6.0 (which is bind to the newest [Proj](https://proj.org/) at least in version 6.2.0) you can even use:

```
from pyproj import Proj, Transformer
import shapely.ops as sp_ops
geom =  # your_shapely_geometry_here
my_transformer = Transformer.from_crs('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857', always_xy=True)
geom_transformed = sp_ops.transform(my_transformer.transform, geom)
```

You don't need the `partial` anymore, I mean.

You can check both [this](https://proj.org/usage/transformation.html) and [this](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/transformer.html).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the problem, I finally used this :

```
line1 = LineString([(0, 0), (180, 0), (360, 0)])
project = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj('EPSG:4326'), pyproj.Proj('EPSG:32633'))
line2 = transform(project, line1)
total_lenght = line2.length
```

and it apparently works.

Answer (score 1):

> 'LineString' object has no attribute 'lenght'

You might want to try **length**, not ***lenght***.